# Rails Migration To Add Index To The Difference Between 2 Columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, indexing, database-migration

In my Ruby on Rails app I have a model `Message` that has a `created_at` column and a `status_updated_at` column. Both of them are datetimes.

In order to speed up queries such as `Message.where(status: 'delivered', account_id: 11).where('status_updated_at - created_at >= ?', "180 seconds")`, I want to add index to the difference between columns `status_updated_at` and `created_at`.

I've tried this code:

```
class AddMessageIndicesForDashboard < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_index :messages, [:status, :account_id, :created_at, "(status_updated_at-created_at)"], name: 'dashboard_delivery_time_index'
  end
end
```

which result in `PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "status_updated_at-created_at" does not exist`

Strangely, say if I only wanted to add index to `status_udpated_at - created_at` by doing `add_index :messages, "(status_updated_at-created_at)", name: 'dashboard_delivery_time_index'`, it will work.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try

```
add_index :messages, "(status_updated_at-created_at)", name: 'dashboard_delivery_time_index'
```

[PostgreSQL(9.1) 11.7. Indexes on Expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/indexes-expressional.html).

> The syntax of the CREATE INDEX command normally requires writing parentheses around index expressions... The parentheses can be omitted when the expression is just a function call...

Since you want to use an expression rather than a function the extra parentheses should do it according to the docs.

Comment: Thanks for the info! It worked. Now say I want to add some other columns together with `status_updated_at - created_at`, it will still throw an error saying PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "(status_updated_at-created_at)" does not exist. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem, you can do `add_index :messages, "status, account_id, (status_updated_at-created_at)", name: 'dashboard_delivery_time_index'`